# Difference between Prior/Posterior density and Prior/Posterior distribution

Tags: distributions, bayesian, prior, posterior

I am confused about the difference between the prior/posterior density and distribution. In my lecture notes the posterior density is:

$$
f(\theta | x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \frac{f(\theta) L(\theta)}{\int f(s)L(s)ds},
$$

where $L$ is the likelihood function and the prior density is $f(\theta)$.

But my notes also say that the posterior distribution is the same as above, with the prior distribution being $f(\theta)$.

So is the prior/posterior distribution and density calculated the same way? Are they the same thing? If not, can someone elaborate on this a bit?

Comment: Distribution is the general name, then you can have both discrete (probability mass function) and continuous (probability density function) distributions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution

Comment: There are also probability distributions are neither discrete nor continuous.

Comment: So the posterior density = f(θ|x1,…,xn)=f(θ)L(θ)∫f(s)L(s)ds, is the same as the posterior distribution = f(θ|x1,…,xn)=f(θ)L(θ)∫f(s)L(s)ds, (the same thing?)